# Android Studio does not notice I changed AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

After importing my Eclipse project I got error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library
> >     W:\android-studio-projects\example\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.5.87\AndroidManifest.xml
> >       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" to
> >     force usage

I think and change my code **AndroidManifest.xml** to

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="9" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" 
/>
```

However, I still get the same error. I have tried to rebuild and restart Android Studio. What can I do, so Android Studio understands I changed the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

minSdkVersion should define in build.gradle file

Comment: In fact remove the `<uses-sdk>` section from your manifest. It gets overridden by values specified in `build.gradle` and it is only confusing to have two different sets of values.